# Only last 4 digits inserted into db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model

In my Contact model, I have the mobile attribute's data type set as integer but when I check my database on postgres, only the last 4 digits of the mobile returns. Would someone please explain to me why this is happening?
This is what I typed in the rails console.

contact6 = Contact.create(name: "luke", address: "878 test st", email: "luke@luke.com", mobile: 666-666-6666)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It treats it as a calculation and returns `-6666` and then inserts it into the db, just as you would expect.

```
mobile: 666-666-6666
```

If you want the mobile number in this format in the db you will have to use a string field, or a text field and insert like this

```
mobile: '666-666-6666'
```

Comment: @anniehswong If it helped click the checkmark underneath the downvote button on the answer. That way people know that the answer has been solved, plus the answerer gets +15 rep.

Comment: @the12 got it. sorry i'm still getting used to stackoverflow.

Comment: @anniehswong If it helped you please click the check mark to the left.